# SASS using mixins (breakpoints) in different file

Tags: sass

i am struggling with breaktpoints in SASS.

I have this file structure

- style.scss
- _layout.scss
- _variables.scss

I wanna use code breakpotints from _variables.scss in _layout.scss

*_variables.scss*

```
$screen-xl-min: 1200px;

@mixin xl {
    @media (min-width: #{$screen-xl-min}) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

*_layout.scss*

```
@use 'variables';
nav {
    height: 80px;
    @include xl {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

*style.scss*

```
@use 'variables';
@use 'layout';
```

And I have error

> SassError: Undefined mixin.

Can someone tell me, what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot for a help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and change

```
@use 'variables'
```

for

```
@use 'variables' as *;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

In your example correct way will be write `@include variables.xl {}`

Or modify `@use` rule like @Café wrote